# TCP ingress support in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

It seems to be TCP and UDP support is going to be deprecated in next version of ingress-nginx controller . Any other ingress controllers supports TCP and UDP ? 
or any other solutions for exposing non-http ports outside kubernetes ?

- kubernetes beginner here *

Comment: you can just use service of type nodePort

Comment: I would suggest the loadbalancer service over nodeport. You can use NodePort for non critical apps. cloud providers also provide internal loadbalancers(simply by specifying the annotation) which are cost effective.

Answer (score 4):

The nginx-ingress (and the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource in K8s for that matter) is a layer 7 facility and doesn't support layer 4, in any case, layer 4 might be supported at some point in the future.  Note that [nginx itself supports layer 4 traffic](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) but not the K8s Ingress.

If you like to directly terminate TCP or UDP you can use standard [Kubernetes services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) and [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) (depending on the cloud provider) types of services should also support TCP/UDP.

Update:

There's a tutorial on how to support TCP/UDP with an nginx ingress (from the NGINX company) [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/tcp-udp).

Comment: LoadBalancer is very expensive, i'm trying open TCP to enable FTP connection with https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/vsftpd/ I found some tutorial to try this and may it could help https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/tcp-udp

Comment: @Alexsandro thanks for the link. I've added it to the answer as an update.