# Ingress controller to route TCP traffic

Tags: nginx, tcp, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to setup an ingress controller(nginx) to forward some TCP traffic to a kubernetes service(GCP). There's [this tutorial](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html) that shows how to route HTTP traffic to services (based on the paths) using nginx. I want to have a similar setup to forward TCP traffic.

In my cluster, I have a pod running a TCP echo server written in python using sockets. There is a service attached to the pod. If I set the service type of this service to LoadBalancer, I can run my client as follows and get the echo from the cluster.

```sh
python client.py --host <EXTERNAL-IP-OF-LOAD-BALANCER> --port <PORT>
```

Similar to the echo server, I have other TCP services in my cluster that serves other pods. Currently I have set all of them to LoadBalancers. So, they have external IPs and listen for traffic on different ports. However, I do not want to create LoadBalancers to all of these services. How would I use the nginx to route the TCP traffic to different services based on the port numbers. If nginx cannot do this, are there other options that I can use to achieve this?

---

UPDATE:
Following the [HangDu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4666002/hang-du)'s answer I created the following files.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: default
data:
  9000: "default/echo-service:50000"
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - name: proxied-tcp-9000
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

Then I used `kubectl create -f <FILE_NAME>` to create the config map and the service. So I was hoping I could use the external IP of the newly created service and the port 9000 and run `python client.py --host <EXTERNAL-IP-OF-LOAD-BALANCER> --port 9000` to run my echo client. However, I get a connection refused error when I do that. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your `nginx-ingress-controller` pod in namespace `default`?

Comment: Yes. I know I should've used multiple namespaces but currently I have the ingress in the default namespace.

Comment: I forgot to add the `"--tcp-services-configmap=default/tcp-services"` to the args in the nginx-ingress pod. It's working now

Comment: @rasthiya how do you add that to the nginx-ingress pod? I installed ingress nginx with the azure installer. It was all set up once it was on my system but that was not shown.

Comment: @mjwrazor I've modified the deployment yaml file. Haven't done anything similar in Azure, but in google GKE you just go to workloads and edit the corresponding yaml file.

Comment: After creating the ingress controller I only see a service but no nginx-ingress pod in any namespace. Am I missing something?

Comment: This configmap makes nginx acting like a LB or we need a Cloud LB anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I answered a similar question on another thread. [How to use nginx ingress TCP service on different namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301394/how-to-use-nginx-ingress-tcp-service-on-different-namespace/57309255#57309255)

Basically, you can specify the port and backend for your service in configmap.

The following is the link to the document.
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

Comment: can you please assist me on my issue?
I desrbibed it completely... Please if you can assist me on similar issue. Although I installed "ingress" as Service in completely different way  using the Helm that is why I am confused... Thank you!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190275/kubernetes-ingress-controller-cannot-tcp-connect-from-outside-virtual-machine